# Importing module of scripts and onload DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What is the difference between doing this:

```
import $ from "jquery";

import { getCurrentYear } from "../utils/global/functions";

$("#year").text(getCurrentYear());
```

and this:

```
import $ from "jquery";

import { getCurrentYear } from "../utils/global/functions";

function setCopyrightYear() {
  $("#year").text(getCurrentYear());
}

$(setCopyrightYear);
```

If I import both modules in the head section of my HTML page like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="module" src="../js/scripts/home.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a function to [`$`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) is equivalent to the [`ready` method](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) which:

> run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate

However, a `<script>` with `type=module` is a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) so:

> There is no need to use the defer attribute (see `<script>` attributes) when loading a module script; **modules are deferred automatically**.

… which has approximately the same effect, making the use of `$(callback)` pointless.